# Regex: using the `u` flag in R

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to remove spaces and unicode word characters not starting a word or number. A simple regex to do that would be

```
\\B\\w+| +
```

with the `u` flag/option. See https://regex101.com/r/QDFrOE/1.

Since the inline modifier `(?u)` isn't a valid modifier, I'm wondering if it possible to set the unicode option in R in another way.

I'm not looking for an equivalent of the regex above using unicode categories. My question is only about the possibility of using the `u` option in R.

**Edit**

Here's a reprex:

```r
s <- c("89 562", "John Smith", "Γιάννης Παπαδόπουλος", "Jean-François Dupuis")
gsub("\\B\\w+| +", "", s, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "85"                  "JS"                  "ΓιάννηςΠαπαδόπουλος"
#> [4] "J-FçoD"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

When the expected output would be:

```
"85", "JS", "ΓΠ", "J-FD"
```

Comment: It would clarify your question to include the test cases here (`strings <- c("89 562", "John Smith", "Γιάννης Παπαδόπουλος", 
"Jean-François Dupuis")`) and show the desired output (e.g. from `gsub(regex, "", strings)` ) ?

Comment: (It sounds from  @user2554330's answer as though the regex you've given here will just work the way you want it to in R ... ?)

Comment: You might consider using unicode regex. eg `\p{L}` to match letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R sets the Unicode option automatically if any of the input strings are marked as being encoded in UTF-8.  Run `Encoding(x)` to see the encodings used for the component elements of `x`.  For example,

```
> Encoding(c("a", "b", "ç"))
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"
```

R prints `"unknown"` for characters that can be represented in 7 bit ASCII (because all supported encodings share those characters), and one of `"latin1"`, `"UTF-8"`, or `"bytes"` for other characters.  Any other encodings need to be converted to one of these to be displayed properly in R.

For example,

```
> strings <- c("89 562", "John Smith", "Γιάννης Παπαδόπουλος",  "Jean-François Dupuis")
> Encoding(strings)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"  
> regex <- "\\B\\w+| +"
> gsub(regex, "", strings)
[1] "85"   "JS"   "ΓΠ"   "J-FD"
```

EDITED to add:

My description above is based on the default regex engine, TRE.  If you switch to PCRE2 by setting `perl = TRUE` in the `gsub()` call, it appears *not* to use the Unicode option:

```
> gsub(regex, "", strings, perl = TRUE)
[1] "85"                  "JS"                  "ΓιάννηςΠαπαδόπουλος" "J-FçoD"
```

This matches the output from your web page without the /u flag.

One more addition:  The `stringr::str_replace_all` function (which I think uses the ICU engine, but the docs are voluminous and I might have missed something) seems to use the same default as TRE:

```
> stringr::str_replace_all(strings, regex, "")
[1] "85"   "JS"   "ΓΠ"   "J-FD"
```

Yet another addition:  This R-devel message https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2023-July/082751.html points out that adding the prefix `"(*UCP)"` to the pattern turns on Unicode property matching.  There's also `"(*UTF8)"` to treat UTF-8 characters as single characters; I'm not sure whether "/u" is equivalent to one or both.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain implications of this? How is it related to regex? Do you want to say that regex will set `/u` flag automatically?

Comment: Yes, "R sets the Unicode option automatically if any of the input strings are marked as being encoded in UTF-8".

Comment: Interesting, I tend to always use the PCRE2 engine so I didn't know R sets the unicode option as default for UTF-8 strings when `perl = FALSE`. This shows that using TRE regex has some advantages over PCRE2 in some cases.

Comment: This is why it's good to always give a fully reproducible example (so e.g. we could see that you were using `perl = TRUE` ...)

Comment: As far as I can see, that looks like a bug in the `perl = TRUE` code.  The help page `?grep` mentions this fact in "Performance considerations", without saying it applies only to `perl = FALSE`.

Comment: I'd encourage you to raise this issue on `r-devel@r-project.org` and/or submit a bug report to `https://bugs.r-project.org` (generally the first is a more visible venue)

Comment: Trivial, but if going to `stringr` anyway then `stringr::str_remove` is a little better than `str_replace` with an empty replacement strnig ...

Comment: oops @user2554430, now that I know who you are (based on your post to r-devel) I realize you don't need to be told about R mailing list/bug list protocol ...